# Scully can´t find empty route

Tags: angular, angular-scully, scully

Scully can´t find my app´s routes, is there something wrong with my routes?

I am on scully version 0.0.19

app.routing.ts looks like this:

```
export const routes: Routes = [

  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('@travel/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule),
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    useHash: false,
    anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
    scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
    onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
    enableTracing: false,
  })],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [MainResolver],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

And in home.routing.ts I have several children routes:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    resolve: {
      response: LandingCampaignResolver,
      rkt: RktCookieResolver
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () => import('@travel/home/header/header.module').then(m => m.HeaderModule),
      },
      {
        path: 'destino/:landing',
        loadChildren: () => import('@travel/home/landing-campaign/landing-campaign.module').then(m => m.LandingCampaignModule),
        data: {
          title: 'Perguntas Frequentes ',
          description: 'Perguntas frequentes sobre o seu seguro viagem. Tipos e valores de coberturas inclusas, problemas com bagagens, assistência seguro e mais. Accesse aqui!\n',
          keywords: ''
        },
        resolve: {
          response: LandingCampaignResolver
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'Sinistros',
        loadChildren: () => import('@travel/home/sinisters/sinisters.module').then(m => m.SinistersModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'DicasViagem',
        loadChildren: () => import('@travel/home/about-travel-insurance/about-travel-insurance.module').then(m => m.AboutTravelInsuranceModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'Ajuda',
        loadChildren: () => import('@travel/home/contact-us-section/contact-us.module').then(m => m.ContactUsSectionModule)
      },
... more routes like these

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [DataPolicyGuard, UdeResponseResolver, LandingCampaignResolver, RktCookieResolver]
})
export class HomeRoutingModule {
}
```

I have also tried the normal path syntax instead of the typescript @ one

Thanks in advance!

**Angular Version:**

```
Angular CLI: 9.0.0-rc.10
Node: 12.14.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 9.0.0-rc.11
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router, service-worker
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.900.0-rc.10
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.900.0-rc.10
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.900.0-rc.10
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.900.0-rc.10
@angular-devkit/core               8.1.3
@angular-devkit/schematics         8.1.3
@angular/cdk                       9.0.0-rc.8
@angular/cli                       9.0.0-rc.10
@angular/flex-layout               7.0.0-beta.24
@angular/http                      7.2.15
@angular/material                  9.0.0-rc.8
@angular/material-moment-adapter   9.0.0-rc.8
@angular/pwa                       0.801.3
@ngtools/webpack                   9.0.0-rc.10
@schematics/angular                8.1.3
@schematics/update                 0.900.0-rc.10
rxjs                               6.5.4
typescript                         3.7.5
webpack                            4.41.2
```

### Error

```
 npm run scully --showGuessError

 ☺   Started servers in background
servers available
Finding all routes in application.

We encountered a problem while reading the routes from your applications source.
This might happen when there are lazy-loaded routes, that are not loaded,
Check the routes in your app, rebuild and retry.
(You can inspect the error by passing the --showGuessError flag

When there are extraRoutes in your config, we will still try to render those.

We did not find an empty route ({path:'', component:rootComponent}) in your app.
This means that the root of your application will be you normal angular app, and
is not rendered by Scully
In some circumstances this can be cause because a redirect like:
   ({path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'})
is not picked up by our scanner.

By adding '' to the extraRoutes array in the scully.config option, you can bypass this issue

No routes found in application, are you sure you installed the router? Terminating.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 15
npm ERR! crux-frontend@0.2.3 scully: `scully`
npm ERR! Exit status 15
```

Comment: is it still there with new version of Scully?

Comment: I am having the same issue exactly. Any idea how to fix it?